# react native receiving push notification from pentaho data service through java backend server

Tags: java, react-native, pentaho

So I am using pentaho data integration to do data transformation. Then, using that transformed data, I would like to let the mobile(react-native) users know if something important changes. So here's my plan to do it.

1. I will set up the java server API in-between react-native and Pentaho.
2. make Pentaho transformed data to be accessible from java API through pentaho data service using JDBC.
3. Java API will check periodically to that data service and compared with previously stored data
4. If something important changes java api will send APNS and GCM to send notification for mobile users

My question then is, 
is this the correct way to do it?

can java api check the pentaho data service periodically?

Comment: The java api can check the service regularly, however it may be easier to use a crontab. It is also possible to send the notification as the last step of your transformation, after testing if something "important" changed. I that case "important"may be the result of a complex sub-transformation.

Comment: hey thank you! So do you mean I can just let the pentaho last step to send notification to mobile apps without java api in-between?

Comment: can you elaborate more on crontab too?

Comment: crontab is a utility installed on any (linux) server. It runs periodically (schedule) task (bash script). Apart of the pain to learn its cryptic language, it is pretty easy to run a PDI every hour (or whatever) that checks the data and send a report to the users.

Comment: I am thinking to use java Quartz to do the cron job. Is it good idea?

Comment: Yes. It is already embedded in the Pentaho server, so it will be easy to maintain even for somebody with no knowledge of command line on the server.